# Were Going To and Would

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

I read this sentence:

> None of us knew if we were gonna go back home again.

I would like to know if the sentence above can be re-phrased differently using the modal 
"would". I was thinking of something like this:

> None of us knew if we would go back home again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, because at the point in the past where this occurred you could say "None of us know if we will go back home again."  You could also say "None of us know if we are going to go back home again."  So, the fact that "I will go" is close to synonymous to "I am going to go" means that "I would go" is close to synonymous with "I was going to go".  They have the same similar senses when placed in the past.

Comment: Thank you BobRodes! These 'feedbacks' help me dramatically to boost my English.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad you find the comment helpful.  p. s. "This feedback" is correct.  This is a so-called "uncountable noun".  :)