# Conditional Sentences (or mixed) why did we use the past outside of the conditional sentence?

Tags: conditionals

I watched a video "English on movies" and met such a sentence that I can't understand:

> I don't think Tony would have done what he did, if he didn't know you
> were gonna be here after he was gone.

I understand, sort of, what conditional and mixed sentences are, but let's
say we have one conditional sentence here:

> I don't think Tony would have done what he did, if he didn't know.

As I understand it the principle works here

- If (Past Simple) + (would have + V3)

But I can't understand why:

> you were gonna be here after he was gone

Why is *the past* here, if we are talking about *the present*, or this is
already another conditional sentence?

Something from these proposals in my head all mixed up.

Comment: It's not the "counter-factual conditional" past tense, it's ordinary back-shifting in reported speech after _know_.

Comment: Unless the fact that Tony knows / knew that you'd be around is ***still relevant at time of speaking***, it would probably be better to refer to his knowledge thereof using Past Perfect *...if he **hadn't known** you **would** be here...* rather than using "past tense do-support".

Comment: Compare *I wouldn't have married you if I **didn't** love you* (by implication, *I still do love you*) with *I wouldn't have hit him if he **hadn't** insulted me* (not normally *...if he **didn't** insult me*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your comment. I seem to understand your comparison and in fact in my example : **he didn't know**  refers to the moment in the past before its decision(also in the past) and is therefore better : **if he hadn't know**?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. As I said in my first comment, Past Perfect is ***probably*** better for your specific example (including the switch from *you were gonna be* to ***would** be*) if you're focused on explaining his ***past*** action. The alternative *if he **didn't know*** is better if the fact of Tony knowing that the addressee would stick around ***is currently still relevant***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you very much for your help,and could you tell me why here: **you were gonna be** we use **were** ,this is more difficult to understand ,according to my logic, I would put a different time here

Comment: For most purposes, *I knew you were gonna be here* (and the "downmarket" ungrammatical, but far from unknown *...knew you **was** gonna...*) is just a slightly more long-winded alternative to *I knew you **would** be here*. It's covered to some extent by [this earlier Q,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21222/were-going-to-and-would) but don't spend too long trying to understand any hypothetical "difference". Mostly there isn't one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks a lot for your help ;)